# Failed build Next.js 13 in Docker container because of relying to another container

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, nestjs, production-environment

So I composed 2 containers consist of Next.js and Nestjs app in Docker. Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '6900:6900'
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./api/.env
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - API_URL=http://api:6900
    environment:
      - API_URL=http://api:6900
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - api
```

then here is `Dockerfile` for the `api`:

```
FROM node:18 as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

RUN npm run prisma:generate

FROM builder as runner

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package*.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist

EXPOSE 6900

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

lastly here is `Dockerfile` for the `web`:

```
FROM node:18 as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

# here we are reading the value from the build args and inserting into the environment variables
ARG API_URL
ENV API_URL=${API_URL}

RUN npm run build

FROM builder as runner
ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN \
  addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs; \
  adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder --link /app/public ./public

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --link --chown=1001:1001 /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --link --chown=1001:1001 /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

When I run `docker compose up --build`, the `api` successfully build and run. However when it comes to build the `web`, especially on `npm run build` it always failed on `Generating static pages`.

It said `fetch failed` and the error cause is `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api`.

**The api container is already up and running but why my Next.js app failed to fetch data from the api when building static pages? Why my Next.js container cannot connect to the Nest.js container?**

Am I missing any steps, please anyone help me. Big thanks~

Comment: Containers can't call each other as part of the build process.  Among other reasons, the build environment isn't connected to the Compose-provided Docker network.  What code is trying to make this cross-service call?

Comment: @DavidMaze in Next.js, when building its trying to generate static pages. Every pages that is server component and has fetch function in it will be build during ``npm run build``. In the build process, Next.js will invoke the fetch function and get some data to be seeded into the static pages. While in my app it fetch to the Nestjs which is the api container, so the api need to be run first and ready to accept request when building the Next.js app.

Comment: @gidgud any alternatives so far, this looks like a blocker that , at build time services are expected to be up. So basically , I can not externalize the environment variables and deploy/change as and when I want. This has become a blocker for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can make entrypoint file with next build/start commands and include it in your Dockerfile.

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

set -e  # Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status

# Install dependencies
npm i || exit 1

# Build the Next.js app
npm run build || exit 1

# Start the app
exec npm run start
```

And than in **Dockerfile** add

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN dos2unix ./entrypoint.sh && chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

This will run Next.js build while containers are running.

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to put the adress or name of the container instead of maybe localhost or something ? It could resolve the issue

Provide your NextJS code if it does not work

Also, if you don't want the page be loaded during build time, you can add :

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

at the end of your file

Comment: The web is relying on the running api when building, that's why when composing up them together it won't recognize the api. I still not find the way to connect web with api using docker IP address / network. So for now my web connect to api using hosted IP address (the api need to run first in a host so it can be consumed by the web when building). And i want to have some static pages on my web.